# Возможно ли сделать SQL запрос, не используя агрегатные функции и вложенные запросы?

Tags: sql

У меня есть БД, вот такого типа: [image: БД]

Мне необходимо сделать SQL запрос:
Тренер, который ведет занятия по нескольким различным видам спорт(НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЯ АГРЕГАТНЫЕ ФУНКЦИИ И ПОДЗАПРОСЫ) возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct t1.id_trener from vid-sporta_trenera t1 
join vid-sporta_trenera t2
on t1.id_trener=t2.id_trener and t1.id_vid_sprt <> t2.id_vid_sprt
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш ответ очень выручил!